# Convert from Int to Long in Hibernate HQL using MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have this HQL Query where I need the value returned from `floor(e.timestamp/(1000*60*60*24))*60*60*24` to be a long, but using cast() does not work because mysql does not accept cast as BigInt or Long. I can't find the correct way to do this.

```sql
SELECT new DayEvent(
e.apiProxyId, 
e.apiKey, 
e.methodId,
floor(e.timestamp/(1000*60*60*24))*60*60*24, 
sum(e.count), 
e.region)                        
FROM Event AS e 
WHERE e.timestamp <= :endTimestamp 
AND e.timestamp >= :startTimestamp 
GROUP BY floor(e.timestamp/(1000*60*60*24)), e.methodId, e.apiKey, e.region, e.apiProxyId`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports cast in HQL:

```
SELECT new DayEvent(
e.apiProxyId, 
e.apiKey, 
e.methodId,
cast(floor(e.timestamp/(1000*60*60*24))*60*60*24 as long), 
sum(e.count), 
e.region)                        
FROM Event AS e 
WHERE e.timestamp <= :endTimestamp 
AND e.timestamp >= :startTimestamp 
GROUP BY floor(e.timestamp/(1000*60*60*24)), e.methodId, e.apiKey, e.region, e.apiProxyId
```

Comment: I did try that, it does not work because MySQL treats long as bigint and it does not have support to cast to bigint. :(